# Is this __VA_ARGS__ expansion valid c99?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-functions, variadic-macros

I am trying to write a function which takes variadic parameters. It has the following prototype:

`void foo(const char *name, const char *file, uint32_t line, const char *fmt, ...);`

and I call it with the following macro:

```
#define FOO(name, ...) \
    foo(name, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

From what I understand the following will be valid:

```
FOO("Example, "Hello %s", "Stack Overflow");
```

But will the following result in undefined behavior in a standards compliant c99 compiler?

```
FOO("Example", "Hello Stack Overflow");
```

My worry is that because the `foo` is expecting both `*fmt` as well as `...` that a trailing `,` will be added when there are only two arguments passed to the macro.

Can anyone tell me if the above is valid c99?

**EDIT:** When I run this with gcc and `std=c99` it works, but I am worried that there is silent UB

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [**6.10.3.1 Argument substitution**, paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.1p2) of the C standard:

> An identifier `__VA_ARGS__` that occurs in the replacement list shall
>   be treated as if it were a parameter, and **the variable arguments shall
>   form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it**.

Thus, `__VA_ARGS__` will be replaced with all the tokens passed as arguments to the macro.

So, in your case, given the macro:

```
#define FOO(name, ...) \
    foo(name, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

called with

```
FOO("Example", "Hello Stack Overflow");
```

and the function declaration

```
void foo(const char *name, const char *file, uint32_t line, const char *fmt, ...);
```

results in something like

```
 foo( "Example", "asdf.c", 1234, "Hello Stack Overflow" );
```

and no undefined behavior in the call to `foo`.  (What happens inside `foo()` might still be UB.)

Comment: "What happens inside foo() might still be UB." - Haha yes, but this is for another day. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I miscounted arguments... All is ok in here. UB will, however, arise if **foo** tries to access anything variadic as stated above.

Comment: @Kamajii - Am I able to call the va_* family of functions on those variadic parameters? Or would that produce UB?

Comment: It would be legal to call `va_start` and `va_end`, which is pretty much what e.g., `printf()` would do with a format string that does not contain placeholders. But you aren't allowed to extract a thing using `va_arg`, obviously.

Comment: @Kamajii Ok perfect. Thanks again to both of you for your time! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

As a side node also related to variadic arguments, C mandates that the variadic part of **the macro** must be supplied at least one argument (which is the case in the original question).

From ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 §6.10.3:4:

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an
>   ellipsis, the number of arguments (including those arguments
>   consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a
>   function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro
>   definition. Otherwise, there shall be **more arguments in the invocation
>   than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...)**.

Also there is a draft addressing this very problem: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2034.htm

Fortunately, most modern compilers either suppress the trailing comma or provide some sort of work around. However, this is compiler specific behaviour.

In the original post the variadic part of the `FOO` macro is given the string literal `"Hello Stack Overflow"`. Upon expansion of the macro the `foo` function might be called as follows:

```
foo("Example", "someFile.c", 42 "Hello Stack Overflow");
```

This is fine, as long as the `foo` function by some means is aware that there are no more arguments to expect after the last fixed argument.

Comment: So the expanded function-call with only 2 macro arguments results in 4 arguments being passed to `foo`. And `foo` has 4 arguments in it's prototype excluding the `...`. Am I understanding that this results in correct behavior?